# Node.js express empty URL params

Tags: node.js, express

I need to define path for the APIs I support in my Node.js express application.
I am facing one issue related to receiving URL variables.

```
// app.js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const addressRouter = require('./routes/address-router');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('port', 8081);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send({
    error: 'path not found',
  });
});

app.use('/v1/users/:userId/zip/:zipNumber/address', addressRouter);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.listen(8081);
```

```
// addressRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/zip-get', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('GET: /zip-get: req: ', req);
  res.send('Done');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The API I am calling:
`curl http://localhost:8081/v1/users/123-456/zip/1234567/address/zip-get`

In the `addressRouter.js` when I print the received req I get:

```
params: {}
```

and

```
baseUrl: '/v1/users/:userId/zip/:zip/address',
originalUrl: '/v1/users/:userId/zip/:zip/address/zip-get',
```

**Update**
In the request object I see below fields:
Does that indicate incoming request is not yet ended?
ReadableState {
objectMode: false,
highWaterMark: 16384,
buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
length: 0,
pipes: [],
**flowing: null,
ended: false,
endEmitted: false,**
reading: false,
sync: true,
needReadable: false,
emittedReadable: false,
readableListening: false,
resumeScheduled: false,
errorEmitted: false,
emitClose: true,
autoDestroy: false,
destroyed: false,
errored: null,
closed: false,
closeEmitted: false,
defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
awaitDrainWriters: null,
multiAwaitDrain: false,
**readingMore: true,
dataEmitted: false,**
decoder: null,
encoding: null,
**[Symbol(kPaused)]: null**
}

I am not sure what can cause this.

Comment: If the question is about `addressRouter`, show its code. No way to tell whether you simply have a typo, called the wrong function, or wrote something wild and crazy that could never work in the first place =)

Comment: Please refer the updated question. I did also try to move the path next to /v1 to the route file but still same issue.

Comment: I don't see your code accessing [req.params](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If you see the line `console.log('GET: /zip-get: req: ', req);` in the file `addressRouter.js` I am logging the `req` object and in the logs I could see `params: {}` is empty, accessing it will result in `{}`. To check the value of the `req.params` I don't need to access it and print empty object, I can clearly make out from the logs that it is empty. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Don't tell "me", tell "everyone" by putting that information in your post instead of in a comment. Also, note that there is no need for `http` if you're using express: your app already has `app.listen()` built in.

Comment: I have this information in the question if you can "read it correctly":
`when I print the received req I get: params: {}` 
It is clear to "everyone" that in the console I am seeing `req.params` as empty.
I will remove the `http` and use only `app.listen()`.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here: as per the official express documentation for [how to handle 404's](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html), you need to move that 404 handler. Express evaluates routes "top down", so your 404 handler is currently kicking in *for everything*.

Also, no need for the `http` module, express is a web server, it already gives you `app.listen` to start the server.

But the most import thing is that routers are [their own thing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). By using them, you are creating a routing context that is *isolated* from the rest of the app, which includes having its own params object that will *only* contain the parameters defined *by* the router itself, so because your `/zip-get` route has no params, the `req.params` object will be empty inside the router's middleware chain.

However, inside the `app.use` middleware chain, which has a path that does have parameters in it, `req.params` *will* have all the values you'd expect, so: copy the values you need from `req.params` into [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) as part of your `app.use` middleware chain, so that any downstream middleware (which includes downstream routers) has access to them.

```js
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/zip-get', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`zip-get stored values:`, res.locals);
  res.send('Done');
});

function copyParams(req, res, next) {
  res.locals = {...req.params};
  console.log(`app level params:`, req.params);
  next();
}

app.use('/v1/users/:userId/zip/:zipNumber/address', copyParams, router);

// This has to come last.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    error: 'path not found',
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => console.log(` http://localhost:8081`));
```

Alternatively, you can tell the router that it should preserve params when you call `new Router` by passing `mergeParams: true` as an option, but then you need to ask yourself why you're using a router at all: express is based on the concept of using a middleware chain to do "individual bits of work, based on the current context", so any code that relies on turning `:userId` and `:zipNumber` into real things should be kicking in before you hit the router middleware, with the intermediary data stored in `res.locals`. The way you've written things, `/zip-get` should not be doing *anything* with those parameters, because it is not responsible for them.

Instead, organize your API by what it needs to do, e.g. have a truly minimal main file:

```js
import express from "express";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";

const app = express();

app.use('/v1/users', userRoutes);

app.use((_req, res, _next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    error: 'path not found',
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => console.log(` http://localhost:8081`));
```

With the user routes being responsible for users, and *only* users:

```js
import express from "express";
import db from "./somewhere-or-other.js";
import zipRoutes from "./zip.js";
...

function findUser(req, res, next) {
  db.getUserById(req.params.userId, (err, user) => {
    if (errr) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.locals.user = user;
    next();
  });
}

const userRoutes = express.Router();
userRoutes.use('/:userId/zip', findUser, zipRoutes);
userRoutes.use('/:userId/something-else', findUser, someOtherRoutes);
export default userRoutes;
```

With a separate zip routes handler:

```
import express from "express";
import db from "./somewhere-or-other.js";
...

function getZipObject(req, res, next) {
  zipManager.getZipObject(req.params.zipNumber, (err, zipData) => {
    if (errr) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.locals.zip = zipData;
    next();
  });
}

const zipRoutes = express.Router();
zipRoutes.get('/:zipNumber/address/zip-get', getZipObject, (req, res) => {
  // Render the page for this route, with res.locals as its context
  // so that the page template can access the user and zip data.
  res.render(`zip-get.html`, res.locals);
});
export default zipRoutes;
```

And note that we're terminating in a function that does *nothing* other than render the appropriate template as page response. All the work that needed to happen should, by the time we hit the final response function, have already been done and turned into `res.local` data that can be passed straight into the template rendering call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after doing these changes I am still not able to receive parameters. May be problem is else where.

Comment: It must be, because the first block of code is fully self-contained (barring the imports), and can be run by copy-pasting it (although I used ESM rather than CJS, mostly because ESM is the "official" way to do imports and exports, whereas CJS is a legacy format that Node invented before ESM existed).

Comment: In the incoming request in the object `ReadableState` I see fields `flowing: null, ended: false, endEmitted: false` does these fields indicate request is not complete yet?

Comment: Instead of trying to keep digging through your code, just take the code I've given you here, which we know works, and build your own code back out based on it.

Comment: With the code you provided I see the same behavior.

Comment: And what behaviour is that, given what user action? because the first code block works perfectly fine when calling the ...../get-zip URL, has the correct params, and sends a response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move the path `/users/:userId/zip/:zip/` up your `addressRouter.js` router's path as you have asked. That's doable since by *default* each router has access to the `req.params` that are defined within its own path.

Another option is to use the optional object to the `express.Router()` function call, that has a property of `mergeParams` and pass it a value of `true` - which would allow you to [*preserve the `req.params` values from the parent router.*](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router)

Modify your `addressRouter.js` into

```js
const express = require('express');
// Here pass in the mergeParams property set to true
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get('/zip-get', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('GET: /zip-get: req: ', req);
  res.send('Done');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did not work for me.